# In-App not working

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, payment

I just integrated the Apple's In-App purchase into my application with 4 products. It was working fine in Sandbox mode before it gets rejected by Apple for not submitting the In-App with the application binary. Once it was rejected it is not fetching the products I was added. It shows no products are there in the list. I checked all the product IDs. But no use.

Deleted the previous products and added new, but still the same problem exists. After that I created new application with 2 products. But once again it shows no products are there...

Any one please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you still have paypal link in your app? In App Purchases and all the Apple Requirements are tough. Can you simply remove the for-sale items and still have a useful app that will be approved.

Are you sure, you are using new product id after creating your new app because this is the unique id that identifies your in-app purchase. Usually it’s best to start out with your bundle id, and then append a unique name for the purchase at the end and what was the type of your product (consumable/non-consumable).

you need to have put your all in-app purchase item for review and Apple will review and approve along with your in-app purchase.

> They would have rejected because your In-app purchase items are still in ready to submit

**Apple review your in-app purchase item as well. so when ever you are adding new in-app purchase item you have to send for review.** hope i could describe you well.

**According to your comment below :**

> Because they might have deleted/rejected you developer account, they are very strict and they flaunt if they find any violation so may be you need to renew your iOS Developer Program membership(can send a mail to them about your story). In addition, your existing Development and Distribution certificates and provisioning profiles will be revoked and invalidated. You will also lose access to pre-release software, available discussion forums, and Developer Technical Support. Because as far as i see that your new unique product is not supporting with your developer account.

**Lets assume you have setup well**

There is **SKProductsRequestDelegate** which gives you **[SKProductsResponse](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsResponse/Reference/Reference.html)** .It has two properties **products** and

> **invalidProductIdentifiers** (An array of product identifier strings that were not recognized by the Apple App Store. (read-only))

```
So what array value you get for invalidProductIdentifiers ?
```

Comment: Hello Friend, 
  I already tried with PayPal. But the thing is my application is somewhat related to Astrology, and the PayPal team told that, they are not supporting the Astrology applications. Thats why I tried with In-App.

Comment: Yes friend. I know that my application was rejected because of my In-App products were not submitted for review with the application. Once apple rejected the application, I tried to test the application once again in the iPhone 4 (device). But the response shows no products are there, but before submitting the app binary to apple it was able to retrieve the products. I used Bundle ID.product name as the Product ID. All the products are consumable. 

 Any idea about this?

Comment: Also after apple rejected my application I created new application in my developer account and added In-App products(product IDs are unique). But while testing using device still getting the same issue (no products for In-App purchase).
 
 So, in simple after rejection, In-App is not working for my developer account (regardless of the application).

Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: @ashok again i have edited my answer according to your comment because in comment box there are character limits and does not support rich format.